# Mouseover event in jQuery response

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, mouseover

**Curent situation**

I have a simple php page where I put my data in a list it has 300k+ products. There is a searchbar which does a elasticsearch and put the founded products in a jquery ajax response:

**Ajax search**

```
   <script>
            $.ajax({
                url: "/product/api/search",
                type: "GET",
                data: 'filter='+$("#f").val(),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#table_id").replaceWith(data);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

**jQuery Select2**

```
<script>
        $('.data-ajax').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: '/product/api/elasticsearch',
                dataType: 'json',
                width: 'resolve', // need to override the changed default
                minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
                dropdownCssClass: 'select2-hidden',

                success: function (data) {
                    var returnedData = data;
                    // clear table
                    $('#snel tbody').empty();

                    for(let i = 0; i < returnedData.results.length; i++){
                        $("#snel").find('tbody')
                            .append($('<tr>')
                                .append($('<td>')
                                    .text(returnedData.results[i].id)
                                )
                                .append($('<td class="columntitle">')
                                    .text(returnedData.results[i].text)
                                )
                                .append($('<td class="columnsku">')
                                    .text(returnedData.results[i].sku)
                                )
                                .append($('<td class="columnvendor">')
                                    .text(returnedData.results[i].vendor)
                                )
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        });    
    </script>
```

**Goal which I want to achieve:**

I need a search bar to search through the products. If I found a product it should show me all other information if I mouse over the SKU for example.

**Question**

- Can I achieve my goal with this setup? If yes How?
- Advices on improvements
- Any suggestion is welcome in order to get a better perspective in resolving this issue.

Comment: Have you considered use any popover plugin to achieve this? Let's say https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/ ?